# What is the purpose of using 'int' in the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the purpose of using `int` in the following code?

```
    sum = sum + int(n % 10)
```

Comment: Where did you find this code? It is not very well written, as it assigns a variable to `sum` which is a built-in. Also, compound assignment is not used.

Comment: the modulus returns you whole numbers, I don't think it has any significance, by the way it'll be better if you ask this question in [Code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), by the way +1 @Tomothy32 's mention, sum is an inbuilt variable.

Comment: @P.hunter mmm well, not necessarily `(3.14 % 10)` does not, so presumably, `n` is not an `int`? Who knows though, it could possibly just be sloppy copy-paste code someone wrote

Comment: @P.hunter this code would be too hypothetical on CR (since we don't know what `n` is and how `sum` is used), and also not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), since the OP doesn't fully understand what it is doing. See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Theoretically, `n` could be of some class the defines `__mod__` in such a way as to return objects that can be turned into `int`s, but are not `int`s.

Comment: Or `n` could be a string, and it is being formatted... (unlikely, though) Without further context, it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is an `int`, it does absolutely nothing, but if `n` is a `float`, it will make sure that the result of the modulo is always an integer.

Example:

```
>>> n = 3.14
>>> n % 10
3.14
>>> int(n % 10)
3
```

The actual reason why this was used and if it was necessary cannot be determined from only that one line in your question. But since that line also overrides the built-in `sum` and doesn't use the `+=` compound assignment, it smells like a poor coder, so probably the usage of `int()` is just an unnecessary oversight.

It's also possible that `n` is an instance of some other class that implements `__mod__` in a weird way, but that's quite inlikely.